# Character counter for input element

Tags: angular, angular-forms

**In Angular, when using template-driven forms, how can I display a character-counter for an input element?**

Caveat: The input element needs to update the model on `blur`, due to my validation logic. But I would like the character counter to update on `change`, i.e. on every keystroke.

```
<input
    type="text" 
    minlength="3"
    maxlength="20"
    required
    [(ngModel)]="model.title"
    name="title"
    #title="ngModel"
    id="title"
    class="form-control"
    [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}
>

<!-- validation -->
<div *ngIf="title.touched && !title.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div *ngIf="title.errors.required">Please enter a title</div>
    <div *ngIf="title.errors.minlength">Too short</div>
</div>

<!-- counter -->
<div class="counter>
    {{ model.title.length }}/20
    <!-- Problem: This way the counter will only update when the model updates -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Edit

You can declare a template reference variable to reference that input element, access the `value` property and count characters, independently by `NgModel`.

```
<input
    type="text" 
    minlength="3"
    required
    [(ngModel)]="model.title"
    name="title"
    #title="ngModel"
    id="title"
    class="form-control"
    [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
    #titleRef
>

The character count is {{titleRef.value.length}}
```

---

#### Previous answer

The evaluation of `title.errors.minlegth` is actually a truthy object, not a boolean.

His content is the following:

```
"requiredLength": 2,
"actualLength": ? // the actual length of your textfield, it gets updated at each keystroke
```

You can bind `{{title.errors.minlength.actualLength}}` wherever you want to get the character count of the title input field. You can bind the visualization only on the `blur` event as well.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question, I'm about to fix it

Comment: Great, I am using the `titleRef` solution!

Comment: If the input had a `maxlength=20` property, would it be possible to get that maxlength somehow to display `Character count is x/20` ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `titleRef.getAttribute('maxlength')`.
Pay attention, it returns a `string`.